# Why are my AdMob ads not shown when I use non-testing IDs?

Tags: android, admob, ads, google-ads-api

Recently, I made an android app. After that, I have opened my account in AdMob and entered my app. I have got an App ID and Unit ID. For the first time, I tested my App with testing ID codes from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-GB#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk). It worked well. But   I have put IDs which are from AdMob in my codes. As a result, It is not displaying.
Here is my Manifest.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapp2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Lotin-Kirill Converter"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp2.Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp2.MainActivity">

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It is build.gradle(:app)

```xml
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.myapp2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView view;
    AdView mAdview;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);


        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + view.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");

    }


    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Lotin-Kirill Converter.")
                    .setMessage("Dasturdan chiqmoqchimisiz?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ha",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }

                            }).setNegativeButton("Yo'q", null).show();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Iltimos, Dasturdan chiqish uchun yana bir marta bosing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

}
```

It is activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


    </WebView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

If you find my mistake, Please help me!
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: It isn't a good practice to show your adUnitId in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newly created admob IDs will not work immediately, you have to wait. From my experience it takes about a day of waiting for the actual IDs to work.

When creating an app that you plan to monetize, create the admob IDs and Ad units ahead of time. You can edit its details later but the IDs will definitely be working when its time for testing and implementing them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up any [`Mediation Group`](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3063564?hl=en)?

If no, then create one.

If yes, then you just have to wait until your request is populated. Will take up some time up to a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

try to test your admob enabled app in other devices. Admob has trouble loading real ads in devices that used for testing it. Also it may take a while for ads to appear